# postgres - inline variable assignment from select

Tags: postgresql, variables, inline-variable

In SQL Server it's possible to do inline variable assignment.

For example, table dbo.tblSynonym:

```html
+--+-------+-----------+
|id|keyword|replacement|
+--+-------+-----------+
|1 |aaa    |bbb        |
|2 |xxx    |yyy        |
|3 |ddd    |eee        |
+--+-------+-----------+
```

when I run this:

`DECLARE @body varchar(max)='aaa111xxx111ddd'
SELECT @body = REPLACE(@body,keyword,replacement) 
FROM dbo.tblSynonym
SELECT @body`

The result should be `bbb111yyy111eee`.

So the value of `@body` will be updated on each row (interaction) and the replace input will be from result of previous rows on the source table.

Is it possible to do something like this in postgres (without cursor)?

Thanks

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Variables can only be used in PL/pgSQL. In "plain SQL" there are no variables. But even PL/pgSQL variables can't be used like that.

Comment: So looks like the only option is to create dynamic code with multiple "replace" according to number of rows in dbo.tblSynonym

Comment: This is impossible to answer unless you show us some sample input data and the expected output (**[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: @NirKa :  have you find any answer to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

```
regexp_replace('Thomas', '.[mN]a.', 'M')  //ThM
```

Look here

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

Comment: I don't see how it helps, the replace needs to occur on the result of the previous replace.